# How to get the number of 200 responses per minute promethues

Tags: prometheus

I have a promethues metric that gives the total response time per second count. Can I get the number of 200 response per minute from this?

metric

```
http_response_time_seconds_count{httpStatusCode="200",ëndpoint="/test"}
http_response_time_seconds_count{httpStatusCode="500",ëndpoint="/test"}
```

I also have the http_total_request but this does not have the httpstatucode

```
http_total_request{endpoint="/test", server="localhost1"}
http_total_request{endpoint="/test", server="localhost2"}
```

I tried a join but it gave me a duplicate value exception

I was thinking of using sum and rate. Would that work

```
sum(rate(http_response_time_seconds_count{httpStatusCode="200",ëndpoint="/test"}[1m]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that makes sense what you want to achieve using this metric. You are trying to compare latency with and number of calls.
This `sum(rate(http_response_time_seconds_count{httpStatusCode="200",ëndpoint="/test"}[1m]))` would give you the rate of time spent within one minute for all the instances that are being scraped, but there is no correlation with the amount of calls that generated this latency.

Comment: https://blog.softwaremill.com/practical-monitoring-with-prometheus-ee09a1dd5527 .. mentions that the number of requests can be found if there is a `count` metric

Comment: it can be, if the counter count the number of request. In this case, as you mentioned, this counter counts the response time spent